# how to check if value from another column is present in every date -mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have a table:

```
date       id    count(sub_id)
2016-03-01 2       1 
2016-03-02 650     1 
2016-03-03 2       1 
2016-03-04 2697    2 
2016-03-05 2       4 
2016-03-06 2697    3
2016-03-07 1000    2 
2016-03-08 2       3 
2016-03-09 2697    3
```

the dates go from 1st march 2016  to 15 march 2016.

i need to check what id is present in every date - from 1 to 15 march.
i.e what user submitted data on every day

so far I have this

```
select submission_date, id, count(submission_id) 
from submissions  
group by submission_date, id
having count(submission_id) >= 1
```

but this only shows the dates and users and how many submissions they made on every day - for example 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `group by id` and check in the `HAVING` clause if the distinct number of dates of each `id` is equal to the distinct number of dates in the table:

```
select id
from submissions  
group by id
having count(distinct submission_date) = (select count(distinct submission_date) from submissions)
```

If there are no duplicate `id`, `submission_date` combinations you can change to:

```
having count(submission_date) = (select count(distinct submission_date) from submissions)
```

and if also there are no `null` dates:

```
having count(*) = (select count(distinct submission_date) from submissions)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `GROUP BY` date

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `date` DATE,
>   `id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`date`, `id`)
> VALUES
>   ('2016-03-01', '2'),
>   ('2016-03-02', '650'),
>   ('2016-03-03', '2'),
>   ('2016-03-04', '2697'),
>   ('2016-03-03', '2697'),
>   ('2016-03-05', '2'),
>   ('2016-03-06', '2697'),
>   ('2016-03-07', '1000'),
>   ('2016-03-08', '2'),
>   ('2016-03-09', '2697');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `date`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `id` ORDER BY `id`)
> FROM table1
> GROUP BY `date`
> ORDER BY `date`
> ```
>
> ```
> date       | GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `id` ORDER BY `id`)
> :--------- | :----------------------------------------
> 2016-03-01 | 2                                        
> 2016-03-02 | 650                                      
> 2016-03-03 | 2,2697                                   
> 2016-03-04 | 2697                                     
> 2016-03-05 | 2                                        
> 2016-03-06 | 2697                                     
> 2016-03-07 | 1000                                     
> 2016-03-08 | 2                                        
> 2016-03-09 | 2697
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9545e14f9f79d5d5b1ab3b9a18270ee9)*

Comment: i never used group_concat.. hmm interesting